# What does "plan well to challenge" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Teachers plan well to challenge and meet the needs of all students.

I read this from a brochure about a school, and does "plan well to challenge" mean "plan well about problems"? I am not sure if "challenge" is used as a noun or verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is parsed as a parallel construction, not as a simple conjunction. In other words, the following is not the correct way of looking at it:

> ✘ Teachers plan well to challenge. Teachers meet the needs of all students.

Instead, the parallel structure of the sentence can be broken down in this way:

> Teachers plan well to (challenge) and (meet the needs of) all students.
>
> → Teachers plan well to *challenge* all students, and teachers plan well  to *meet the needs of* all students.

It means that teachers not only plan to provide an environment in which students struggle to overcome obstacles (they can't just be lazy about their education), but also plan for a structure that will be good for them.

*Challenge* is being used as a verb.

Answer (score -1):

In this use the pamphlet means they intend to make a plan to provide a mental exercise that will not be too easy for the students so as to help them improve.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. You’ve dashed off quite a few answers already, but they are lacking explanation of “why” and are full of spelling and “autocorrect” mistakes. You’ve explained what the sentence means without actually answering the question about the phrase. You may want to look over [How to write a good answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and the [Answering Questions section](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4786/9161) of the Contributor’s Guide.

Comment: Then does this sentence mean "Teachers plan well to challenge students, and they meet the needs of all students."?

Comment: Thank you Colleen.

Comment: @jay Why did you [delete this question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/222142/what-do-seeing-as-it-and-as-only-he-could-mean) If you undelete it I'll write you an answer.